# Nifi Regex Evaluation

Tags: apache-nifi

I am having a case in my current flow where i want to evaluate certain attributes in my flow file. This is current structure of my flowfilw:

```
{
Attribute1: Value
Attribute2: Value
.
Attribute k: Value
.
}
```

(i) So say for example, evaluate if attribute 2 is an integer of length 9. If it isn't Set the value of Attribute k to 'not valid'.

What processor or a combination of processor (maximum of 2) can i use to do this? Also can you write the underlying Expression Language for the case i just mentioned as i am new to this technology and i need to get it done soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `UpdateAttribute` processor to modify the value of an attribute. It can use Expression Language as you said to evaluate the value of other attributes in order to accomplish that. The below should work:

Property name: `Attribute k`
Property value: (one of the following expressions)

Expression options (in order of recommendation):

- Check for exactly 9 digits using regex: `${Attribute1:find('^\d{9}$'):ifElse(${"Attribute k"}, 'not valid')}`
- Check numerically: `${Attribute1:ge(100000000):and(${Attribute1:lt(1000000000)}):ifElse(${"Attribute k"}, 'not valid')}`
- Check with string length & type coercion: `${Attribute1:length():eq(9):and(${Attribute1:toNumber():gt(0)}):ifElse(${"Attribute k"}, 'not valid')}`